# How to do Cut Copy Paste in Java

Tags: java, clipboard

I want to make a java program that can access the clipboard for performing functions like cut,copy and paste. It would be much helpful if someone would kindly help me with a sample code...
Thank You!

Comment: Use java.awt.datatransfer package and do r&d

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/Clipboard.html

Answer (score 4):

```
     /**
     * get string from Clipboard
     */
    public static String getSysClipboardText() {
        String ret = "";
        Clipboard sysClip = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();

        Transferable clipTf = sysClip.getContents(null);

        if (clipTf != null) {

            if (clipTf.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor)) {
                try {
                    ret = (String) clipTf
                            .getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }

    /**
     * put string into Clipboard
     */
    public static void setSysClipboardText(String writeMe) {
        Clipboard clip = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        Transferable tText = new StringSelection(writeMe);
        clip.setContents(tText, null);
    }

    /**
     * get image from Clipboard
     */
    public static Image getImageFromClipboard() throws Exception {
        Clipboard sysc = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        Transferable cc = sysc.getContents(null);
        if (cc == null)
            return null;
        else if (cc.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.imageFlavor))
            return (Image) cc.getTransferData(DataFlavor.imageFlavor);
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * put iamge into Clipboard
     */
    public static void setClipboardImage(final Image image) {
        Transferable trans = new Transferable() {
            public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {
                return new DataFlavor[] { DataFlavor.imageFlavor };
            }

            public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor flavor) {
                return DataFlavor.imageFlavor.equals(flavor);
            }

            public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor)
                    throws UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException {
                if (isDataFlavorSupported(flavor))
                    return image;
                throw new UnsupportedFlavorException(flavor);
            }

        };
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(trans,
                null);
    }
```

and if you want to handle files or folders you may try

```
 copyFile(srcPath, destDir, true/**overwriteExistFile*/);    

 copyDirectory(srcPath, destDir, true/**overwriteExistDir*/);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example of string copying for JDK 7+ (JavaFX 2):

```
public String pasteFromClipboard() {
    return Clipboard.getSystemClipboard().getString();
}

public void copyToClipboard(String text) {
    HashMap<DataFormat, Object> map = new HashMap<DataFormat, Object>();
    map.put(DataFormat.PLAIN_TEXT, text);
    Clipboard.getSystemClipboard().setContent(map);
}
```

[JavaDoc for Clipboard](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/input/Clipboard.html).